# jQuery 1.8.1 data() error retrieving HTML5 data-attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to extract the FIRST data attribute from the following mark-up:

```
<button class="buttonMiddle" data-vid="1">
    <a href="#">who helped them</a>
</button>

<button class="buttonMiddle" data-vid="2">
    <a href="#">who helped them</a>
</button>
```

the JS I've conjured is:

```
var button1 = $('.buttonMiddle').get(0).data('vid');

console.log(button1);
```

Chrome's console gives me this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'data'

I've covered the basic troubleshooting --> jQuery is loaded before this js file, they are both loaded just before the closing body tag (so no need for `$(function() {// find data-attribute});`.

Comment: `.get()` will get you a DOM Element - if you want to use `.data()` you need a jQuery object because `.data()` is a jQuery method so using `.eq()` will return a jQuery object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead of `get()` here:

```
var button1 = $('.buttonMiddle').eq(0).data('vid');
```

Comment: Perfect, thats the solution! For anyone else who comes by this, if you want to read more on @wirey's explanation check it out here --> http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Comment: Be careful about key that must be lowercase when using $(selector).data(<lowercase param name>) no matter how defined Upper or Lower case. Or using full parameter names with original case when you use $(selector).attr(<full param name>).